# How can I print current time as an ISO 8601 string with strftime?

Tags: c, posix, strftime

I want to print the current time in ISO 8601 format as close as possible to Python's `isoformat()` function, which produces output like `2024-01-16T09:32:46.090+01:00`.

As a starting point, I have this code that uses `gettimeofday()`, `localtime()`, and `strftime()`:

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(){
  struct timeval tv; 
  struct timezone tz;

  gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);

  char buf[30]; // 29 chars + '\0'
  strftime(buf, 30, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z", localtime(&tv.tv_sec));

  printf("using strftime: %s\n", buf);
}
```

That generates `2024-01-16T09:32:46+01:00` (missing milliseconds).

I didn't not find any format specifier for [`strftime()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) to print milliseconds.

Comment: See [Getting current time with milliseconds](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/11921/75307) on Code Review.  Although it's tagged C++, the code being reviewed uses the C portion of the Standard Library (and even omits the `std::` namespace qualifier), so there is plenty to inform this question.

Comment: You could format leaving a gap for the milliseconds, and fill that in later: `size_t end = strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%FT%T.   %z"); sprintf(end-8, "%03d" millis)`.  You could even use that as a starting point to insert the `:` into time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strftime()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) takes a [`struct tm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tm.3type.html) as input, and `struct tm` has no notion of milliseconds/microseconds so `strftime()` can't get milliseconds out of it.

In order to the the milliseconds you will need to resort to the [`struct timeval`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timeval.3type.html) returned by [`gettimeofday()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/settimeofday.2.html) which has a member called `tv_usec` with the microseconds that you can easily convert to milliseconds by dividing by 1000. Or use [`clock_gettime()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html) which provides nanoseconds. See an example with `clock_gettime` at the bottom.

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(){
  struct timeval tv; 
  struct timezone tz;

  gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);

  char buf[sizeof "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999+0000"]; // 28 chars + '\0'
  size_t bufsize = sizeof buf;
  int off = 0;
  struct tm *local = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
  off = strftime(buf, bufsize, "%FT%T", local); // same as "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
  off += snprintf(buf+off, bufsize-off, ".%03d", tv.tv_usec/1000);
  off += strftime(buf+off, bufsize-off, "%z", local);

  printf("using strftime: %s\n", buf);
}
```

When executed it will produce `2024-01-16T14:08:15.079+0100` which matches ISO 8601 with milliseconds and UTC offset. Unfortunately the `%z` produces a UTC offset in the form `+0100` (no colon) instead of `+01:00`

```
gcc test.c -g -Wall -std=c11 && ./a.out
using strftime: 2024-01-16T14:08:15.079+0100
```

If you really really need the UTC offset with colon, then you can use `struct timezone` from `gettimeofday()`. You need to replace the `off += strftime(buf+off, 30-off, "%z", local);` to more convoluted:

```
  if (tz.tz_minuteswest >= 0) {
    off += snprintf(buf+off, 30-off, "+%02d:%02d", tz.tz_minuteswest/60, tz.tz_minuteswest%60);
  } else {
    off += snprintf(buf+off, 30-off, "-%02d:%02d", -tz.tz_minuteswest/60, -tz.tz_minuteswest%60);
  }
```

Note that `gettimeofday()` is considered deprecated in favor of `clock_gettime()`, so the best way to do all this would be:

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf
#include <stdlib.h> // labs
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(){
  struct timespec tp;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);

  char buf[sizeof "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999+00:00"]; // 29 chars + '\0'
  size_t bufsize = sizeof buf;
  int off = 0;
  struct tm *local = localtime(&tp.tv_sec);
  off = strftime(buf, bufsize, "%FT%T", local); // same as "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" 
  off += snprintf(buf+off, bufsize-off, ".%03ld", tp.tv_nsec/1000000);
  off += snprintf(buf+off, bufsize-off, "%c%02ld:%02ld", local->tm_gmtoff >= 0 ? '+' : '-', labs(local->tm_gmtoff)/3600, labs(local->tm_gmtoff)%3600/60); 

  printf("using strftime: %s\n", buf);
}
```

The only changes are to use `clock_gettime()` instead of `gettimeofday()` and use the time zone information that [`localtime()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) provides in the `struct tm` as `tm_gmtoff`.

```
gcc test.c -g -Wall -std=c11

TZ="Europe/Madrid" ./a.out;
using strftime: 2024-01-16T16:18:12.161+01:00

TZ="America/Anchorage" ./a.out; 
using strftime: 2024-01-16T06:18:12.173-09:00

TZ="UTC" ./a.out
using strftime: 2024-01-16T15:18:12.184+00:00

TZ="Asia/Kolkata" ./a.out
using strftime: 2024-01-16T23:38:31.766+05:30
```

Comment: The `clock_gettime` example needs to further divide the GMT offset minutes by 60 after the _% 3600_ — it is wrong, for example, for `TZ=Asia/Kolkata`.  Also, it needs `stdlib.h` for `labs()`.

Comment: @TobySpeight , I updated the snippets to use `sizeof` and `%F` and `%T` , @pilcrow I fixed the incorrect calculation of the minutes in the utc offset. Thanks to you both!

Comment: C11 and later has the [§7.27.2.5 The `timespec_get` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.5) function, which is isomorphic to `clock_gettime()` — it does the same job but is in Standard C rather than POSIX.  I'm not sure how widely available `timespec_get()` is.